# Is there an xfce globalmenu plugin for 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, xfce, globalmenu

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on my netbook, and I've recently switched to xfce as unity was a bit to hefty on the processor.

One of the features I liked about unity was the global menu in the top panel (saved space on the tiny screen) so I've been trying to replicate it. However everything I've found appears to be out of date (only applying for 11.04 and 11.10).

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

If you  want to save some vertical screen space, try installing [maximus](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/maximus), which removes the titlebar.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the official repositories, but you can download the source of the Xfce4 patch [here](http://gnome2-globalmenu.googlecode.com/files/gnome-globalmenu-0.7.8.tar.bz2) and build it using `./configure` and `make install`.

---

## Update for Ubuntu 16.04

Since Ubuntu 16.04 (and higher, currently up to 17.10), a globalmenu plugin called **topmenu** is available for Xfce and MATE:

```
# apt install xfce4-topmenu-plugin topmenu-gtk2 topmenu-gtk3
```

(Required packages differ for MATE, but this question is about Xfce.)

This implementation is not perfect (yet), as some applications are not yet supported. However, the Ubuntu MATE distribution has topmenu preinstalled since Ubuntu MATE 17.04, so it seems like it will be getting "official" status soon, thus receiving more support.